# Aliases for primitive types in AVRO

Tags: avro

I want to define aliases/logical names for primitive types. But if I do that directly like for PartyId in the example below, Avro-Tools do not accept this:

```
protocol Test {
    string PartyId;

    record Header {
        PartyId partyId;
    }
}
```

Is that possible in IDL or AVRO Schema language? How? As a work-around, I can define:

```
record PartyId {
    string _value;
}
```

Though binary this seems equivalent, semantically (e.g. in generated Java code) this is not the same - PartyId is a structured type, not a primitive type.

I can define custom names for enums and records, but it seems to me that AVRO doesn't offer means for aliasing primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases in Avro are for remapping of record namespaces

Names for records and enums are because these are actual objects, not primitives

Just like you cannot refer to a Java String by another class, Avro has no need for such a feature. You can write doc comments or name the fields appropriately to make it clear what each field is

Comment: OK. I'm comparing AVRO with XSD, and XSD allows custom names for primitive types. And so does most of the common programming languages (C, C++, C#, Python etc.) - apart from Java, of course. I take it that AVRO was tailored for Java.

Comment: ... strictly speaking, those languages allow definitions that are syntactically similar to primitive types. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Define_a_primitive_data_type

Comment: That link mostly shows examples of wrapper classes with constructor validation, which I wouldn't call primitives, let alone aliases

Comment: @OneCrickteer In some of the languages you are able to define true primitive types. In other languages you can create classes or structures that look and behave like primitive types. But I do not want to discus this here. Here it suffices to compare AVRO with XSD - this is what I expected from AVRO.